# How to remove map outline in tmap?

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, tmap

For example, if I want to remove the rectangle around the map below, what should I proceed? Thanks in advance for any help.

**Here is my code:**

```
tm_shape(Europe[Europe$name=="Austria", ]) +
    tm_polygons()
```

**This is the result:**

[image]

T**his is the desired output:**

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set that parameter, and many others in the **tm_layout()** function. In this case just set the *frame* argument to be false

```
library(tmap)
data(World)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("HPI") + 
  tm_layout(frame = FALSE)
```